# select statement with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data like below

```
ID           Status          W_ID
1          In Progress        7
2          In Progress        5
3          Complete           5
4          In Progress       NULL
5          Complete           7
```

I want select record where the status is 'In progress' with the W_ID is NULL or W_ID is 5

The result is like

```
ID           Status          W_ID
2          In Progress        5
4          In Progress       NULL
```

How I should write the select query?

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: try `select * from <table> where Status = 'In Progress' and (W_ID is null or W_ID = '5')`

Comment: `select * from your table where status = "In progress" and W_ID is null or  W_ID =5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE Status = 'In Progress' AND (W_ID IS NULL OR W_ID = 5)
```

Or

```
WHERE Status = 'In Progress' AND ISNULL(W_ID,5)= 5
```

Comment: Thanks.  Why I'm so stupid...keep stuck there with just a simple query.  keep stuck in the where clause with "Where Status != 'Complete' "

Answer (score 0):

Try as below , its very simple you jut have to apply 'and' & 'or' condition.

```
Select * from table where Status = 'In Progress' and  (W_ID is NULL or W_ID = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query, It fetches records with In Progress as status

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Status ='In Progress' AND (ISNULL(W_ID,0) = 0 OR ISNULL(W_ID,0) = 5)
```